# How to setup the ssh-proxy of stackedit?

Tags: markdown, stackedit

I want to publish .md files from [stackedit](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit) to my local drive via SSH server, but I cannot figure out how to setup and configure the [ssh-proxy](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit-ssh-proxy) of stackedit.

The setup of stackedit on my host was OK, I can run it from my host in any browser. The node server for ssh-proxy could also start, but I'm lost how to setup stackedit and its ssh-proxy, to get them to play together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documents edited by means of StackEdit can be stored successfully into my local server without a public ip address but with open ssh installed. Precisely the local server is a cygwin ssh server on my note book.

Please follow the instructions from https://github.com/benweet/stackedit-ssh-proxy, briefly as following

1. git clone https://github.com/benweet/stackedit-ssh-proxy.git
2. cd stackedit-ssh-proxy-master
3. npm install
4. node server.js
5. Change SSH proxy in StackEdit to `http://localhost:9999/`.